# Existence of constant of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following dynamical system
$$\begin{cases}\dot x = y-\varepsilon (x^2+y^2)x \\ \dot y=-x-\varepsilon(x^2+y^2)y\end{cases} $$
There exists some integral of motion (or constant of motion, that is a function which is constant on the solutions of the dynamical system) depending on $\varepsilon$? If not why?

I tried building (with "hands") an Hamiltonian in a right way (that is a function which derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are the r.h.s. of my system...), without success. What I expected was to find none integral of motion. The original problem was a counter example of the theorem of Poincare about the continuation of the periodic orbits: if a was able to show an integral of motion (depending on $ε$), I could state the existence of a periodic orbit for the perturbed system, "near" the periodic orbit of unperturbed system: $x(t)=\cos t$ and $y(t)=\sin t$. But using the Lyapunov function $V=x^2+y^2$, one can see that there is no periodic orbit: the origin is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing special, just to build (with "hands") an Hamiltonian in a right way ( that is a function which derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are the r.h.s. of my system...

Comment: In polar coordinates, the system of equations reads $$\begin{cases}\dot{r} = -\epsilon r^3 \\ \dot{\theta} = -1\\ \end{cases}$$ Does this help?

Comment: Sorry, but I never study techniques to show an integral of motion. What should I see?

Comment: You can solve the equation explicitly now. Then rearrange to find constants (aka eliminate $t$)

Comment: What I expected was to find none integral of motion. The original problem was a counter example of the theorem of Poincare about the 
continuation of the periodic orbits: if a was able to show an integral of motion (depending on $\varepsilon$), I could state the existence of a periodic orbit for the perturbed system, "near" the periodic orbit of unperturbed system: $x(t)=cost$ and $y(t)=sint$. But using the Lypunov function $V=x^2+y^2$, one can sees that there is no periodic orbit: the origin is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point. Can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108040/discussion-between-jason-and-ninad-munshi).